# Passing HTML or Components to the Vue Plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created the basic Vue component which is as follow.

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    /* here render the component or HTML passed by pluing */
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Example',
});
</script>
```

Now I need to create a plugin that will render any HTML or Component passed to the `Example`.I know the basic syntax of plugins and how to use them in the Vue but don't know how to do this task since I am a newbie to `Vue`.

```
export default {
    install(vue, opts){ 
      /* how to take the component or HTML and pass to `Example` Component */
    }
}
```

I need to implement these in vue2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `slot` to render an arbitrary HTML inside any of your components.

Your Example Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Example',
});
</script>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<template>
  <example>
    <div>Render me inside the slot</div>
  </example>
</template>
```

And it will result in the following rendered HTML:

```html
<div class="example">
  <div>Render me inside the slot</div>
</div>
```

Then in you plugin you can use your Example component and pass any html you want to it

Update: this how your plugin might look like. Just create a global component inside of it

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const ExamplePlugin = {
  install(Vue){
    Vue.component('Example', {
      name: 'Example',
      template: '<div class="example"><slot /></div>'
    })
  }
}
```

Then you can `Vue.use(ExamplePlugin)` and `Example` component will be available globally in your application

Comment: can you please describe in detail that how to create a plugin of it and more importantly how we pass this argument to the plugin after creation.can create the plugin of it.

Comment: What is the purpose of this plugin? How are you going to use it? Do you want to publish it to npm? In most cases components will suit your needs.

Comment: I need to create a plugin for an app so we can use this feature such as `example` using `Vue.use` and also develop this part of the app apart from the main app.

Comment: Update my answer with the actual plugin code